# Changing Field that Attribute Window orders Layers in using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, editing, list

[image]

How do I change the field that orders the attributes?

As you can see, STRUCT_TYP has the same value for each attribute.  I would like to change it to STRUCT_ID.

Is this possible using ArcMap?

I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Properties tab for the layer, go to the Display tab. Use the dropdown under Display Expression to set the field to Struct_ID. Then save that option. If you don't want to have to do this every time you add the feature to a map, save the layer to an lyr file and add the data using that lyr file. Or, add it to a template map if you use those. Unfortunately, ArcMap will pick the first text field usually, often a bad choice, if you don't tell it otherwise.